# using pointer to function to asm file?

Tags: c++, c

Im reading a book, where there is a program wrote in C to execute shellcodes. I copied it, but it doesnt work, so i tried to fix it. I found that i should use mmap func to allocate memory dynamcly, and also get the proper permissions, but it also doesnt work. Here is an example of an asm file:

test.asm:
     xor eax, eax
     mov eax, 1

Then I compiled it with "nasm -o test test.S

Then to call the asm module, the book implement the following code in C:

```
void *code;
void (*func) (void);    // pointer to function
code = malloc(funcLen);   // funcLen, size of asm file compiled
FILE *fp = fopen("test", "rb");
fread(code,1, funcLen, fp);

func = (void (*) (void)) code;
(*fptr) ();
```

but when I run it , it throws me the error "Segmentation fault (code dump)". So I look around and found the mmap function, and the code ends:

```
void *code;
void (*func) (void);    // pointer to function
code = mmap(NULL, funcLen, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); // funcLen, size of asm file compiled
FILE *fp = fopen("test", "rb");
fread(code,1, funcLen, fp);

func = (void (*) (void)) code;
(*fptr) ();
```

And that still doesnt work, how can i asign memory with execution permissions?
Thank you

Comment: As long as you don't return from your test.asm, your code will execute random statements after the two statements you wrote. Best single-step the program using a debugger to see what happens. Your crashes do not neccesarily result from executing a non-executable segment. Also, unless you made a copy/paste error, assigning the code to *func*, then calling *fptr*, seems incorrect.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm  fptr was incorrect. I meant func, sorry. The complete asm code that i use is the following:
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
jmp short string
code:
pop ecx
mov bl, 1
mov dl, 14
mov al, 4
int 0x80
dec bl
mov al, 1
int 0x80
string:
call code
db 'Hello, world!', 0x0a
And with that code I have an error, and when I compile it as an elf file it works well. That is why im assuming, the problem is from executing non-executable segment. Gdb debugger throws me the following error:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ff700c in ?? ()

Comment: Your mmap *seems* correct except you don't show us how funcLen is calculated. Still, the best thing to debug this is use gdb and single-step. You can check /proc/<your pid>/maps as well just before the call to your function to check if you really got a writable and executable map, i'm not sure if current kernels don't prevent this. In that case, you could still open your test code file and mmap fileno(fp) so you get an executable map, no need to specify PROT_WRITE in that case. I hope your "test" is a raw binary, not an ELF file.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I calculate funcLen so: struct stat sbuf; if(stat(argv[2], &sbuf)) /*argv[2] is the asm compiled file name*/ funcLen = (long) sbuf.st_size; 
Test is compiled so: 'nasm -o test test.S'
I test fileno(fp), but it still throwing me, segmentation fault error